# Removing the Div that a clicked Element is inside of

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove the parent div from the page when you click an href inside the div. There can be more than one of the same div, or I would just use the class name. I tried to use $(this).remove(); but that only removes the delete button. I have looked into parent attributes, but I am not sure I completely understand how that works.

This is what I have:

```
<script>        
 $(".delete-button").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();           
 });
</script>


 <div class="bottomsurgicalhistory">

  "Div Content is Here"
  <li class="delete"><a href="#"  class="delete-button"></a></li>
 </div>

 <div class="bottomsurgicalhistory">

  "Div Content is Here"
  <li class="delete"><a href="#"  class="delete-button"></a></li>
 </div>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `$(this).closest(".bottomsurgicalhistory").remove();`. In your HTML, you could easily use `$(this).parent().remove();`. Here's the docs for `closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ . It's nice/reliable to use when you're not sure how nested an element would be, but you know some ancestor will match the selector and will work

Comment: Note that LI elements should be inside an UL, I'm guessing this is just pseudo code, but still !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the script tag comes before the elements, you'll need a dom ready function, and preventing the default scrolling to the top when using a hash as a href is usually good idea. When clicking the delete button, use `closest()` to find the closest parent that mathes the `bottomsurgicalhistory` class :

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete-button").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.bottomsurgicalhistory').remove();           
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your following code:

```
$(this).remove();
```

for this one:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```